# Using fetch to post JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to do a post of multiple points of data from a form input.

However,  the form data doesn't reach json output payload (I checked the network output). It seems to never get triggered.

If there's a better way to re-write this- I am open to it

I've put it all into Codepen- http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/LRVgpo?editors=1011

The data needs to be posted in this exact way:

```
{
        "title": "SAMPLE",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Movie",
                "taglevel": 1,
            }
        ],
        "info": []
    }
```

## Post method

```
    var Postapi = React.createClass({
componentWillMount () {
var form = document.querySelector('form')
return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/Data/', {
 method: 'POST',
 body: JSON.stringify({
     title: this.state.itemtitle,
     tag:[
       {name:this.state.tagtitle,
       taglevel:this.state.taglevel}
      ],
     info:[]
  })
})
```

},

## Sample return

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
 ...
  <input
    placeholder="Item Title"
    type="text"
    itemtitle={this.state.itemtitle}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
```

## Initial state & submit

```
  getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    itemtitle: [],
    tagtitle: [],
    taglevel: [],
    tagoptions: Exampledata
  };
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({itemtitle: event.target.itemtitle});
    this.setState({tagtitle: event.target.tagtitle});
    this.setState({tagname: event.target.tagname});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemtitle = this.state.itemtitle
    var tagtitle = this.state.tagtitle
    var taglevel = this.state.taglevel
    this.setState({itemtitle: '', text: ''});
  },
```

Comment: This is missing an end bracket `JSON.stringify({
         title: this.state.itemtitle,
         tag:[{
         name:this.state.tagtitle,
         taglevel:this.state.taglevel,
         }],
         info:[], <<<< here`

Comment: Nope that didn't help. The code tells me I need a bracket to end it with (which gives an error too). Any other advice?

Comment: `}),` is what you need

Comment: This has not helped. I feel like my data is not being passed from my form to my json post data either. Please see the updated http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/LRVgpo

Comment: It was still a huge problem regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call your `fetch` function in `handlesubmit` function...according to this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm) , `componentWillMount : is executed before rendering, on both server and client side.` so your form is empty.
you need read more about react life cycle.